# Issue with UI while updating storyBoard from Xcode8 to Xcode9

Tags: ios, xcode, safearealayoutguide

I am trying to run my project on iphoneX. I have already updated my safe area layout guide but still, I am getting black bars on top and bottom. I tried all the possible ways which I know. I have also tried copy and paste my  view controller to new xcode project and I found it working perfectly on new project.

Comment: What are you using a Launch screen or images?

Comment: I am using launch Image.

Comment: You need to add launch image for iPhone X resolution.

Comment: Now, I switched to launch screen and its working perfectly. Thanks, for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use launch image then in Assets you have to select iOS 8.0 and later 
 you can see below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check `Project -> Build Setting -> Architectures -> Valid Architectures` are included `arm64 armv7 armv7s` ?